# MVC @if statements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web

Just trying to write simple if statement to check whether a model has a certain string value. Currently I have this

```
@if (offer.Title === "Offer")
{
    //do something
}
```

I know I have results where the title does equal "Offer" but nothing is displaying on my webpage. I don't normally write MVC (hence the noobie question) but I figured this would be pretty simple so just went for it myself..

Comment: change `===` to `==`

Comment: what do you have inside the if block

Comment: Cheers, double == worked

Comment: I dont know what is offere, if u need to check ur model.title value, then `@if (Model.Title =="Offer")
{
    //do something
}`

Comment: What is `offer` and how have you declared it in the view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the C# reference, the existing [equality operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx#Anchor_6) are:

==

> By default, for reference types other than string, this returns
>   reference equality (identity test). However, types can overload ==, so
>   if your intent is to test identity, it is best to use the
>   ReferenceEquals method on object.

!=

> not equal. See comment for ==. If a type overloads ==, then it must
>   overload !=

So the outcome is that there is no triple equality operator, you have got to use the double equality operator. Note: in other languages the triple equality operator `===` would also check for the type equality not just the value equality, but since C# is a type safe language there is no need for the triple.